# Glassfish does not start up

Tags: glassfish, glassfish-4

Today i reinstalled my Glassfish Server and added 
it to my eclipse java web project. When i try to
start it it takes extremly much time. after 30 Minutes
of loading he arrived 69% of his starting progress.
Now he does not get further. No Errors are in the log,
he is still trying to start the glassfish server after
two hours now. Still at 69%.

The Log:

```
[2013-12-11T21:31:18.593+0100] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [NCLS-LOGGING-00009] [javax.enterprise.logging] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1386793878593] [levelValue: 800] [[
Running GlassFish Version: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.0  (build 89)]]

[2013-12-11T21:31:18.595+0100] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [NCLS-LOGGING-00010] [javax.enterprise.logging] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1386793878595] [levelValue: 800] [[
Server log file is using Formatter class: com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.ODLLogFormatter]]

[2013-12-11T21:31:18.709+0100] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.core.security.com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1386793878709] [levelValue: 800] [[
SEC1115: Realm [admin-realm] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.]]

[2013-12-11T21:31:18.715+0100] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.core.security.com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1386793878715] [levelValue: 800] [[
SEC1115: Realm [file] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.]]

[2013-12-11T21:31:18.718+0100] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.core.security.com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1386793878718] [levelValue: 800] [[
SEC1115: Realm [certificate] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.certificate.CertificateRealm] successfully created.]]

[2013-12-11T21:31:18.980+0100] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1386793878980] [levelValue: 800] [[
Grizzly Framework 2.3.1 started in: 29ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8.080]]]

[2013-12-11T21:31:19.005+0100] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1386793879005] [levelValue: 800] [[
Grizzly Framework 2.3.1 started in: 2ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8.181]]]

[2013-12-11T21:31:19.032+0100] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1386793879032] [levelValue: 800] [[
Grizzly Framework 2.3.1 started in: 3ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:4.848]]]

[2013-12-11T21:31:19.118+0100] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.core.security.org.glassfish.security.services.impl.authorization] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1386793879118] [levelValue: 800] [[
Authorization Service has successfully initialized.]]

[2013-12-11T21:31:19.228+0100] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1386793879228] [levelValue: 800] [[
Grizzly Framework 2.3.1 started in: 1ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:3.700]]]

[2013-12-11T21:31:19.235+0100] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [org.glassfish.ha.store.spi.BackingStoreFactoryRegistry] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1386793879235] [levelValue: 800] [[
Registered org.glassfish.ha.store.adapter.cache.ShoalBackingStoreProxy for persistence-type = replicated in BackingStoreFactoryRegistry]]

[2013-12-11T21:31:19.324+0100] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1386793879324] [levelValue: 800] [[
HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.0.0.Final]]

[2013-12-11T21:31:19.788+0100] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [NCLS-CORE-00017] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1386793879788] [levelValue: 800] [[
GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.0  (89) startup time : Felix (6.921ms), startup services(1.274ms), total(8.195ms)]]

[2013-12-11T21:31:19.838+0100] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler] [tid: _ThreadID=63 _ThreadName=pool-16-thread-1] [timeMillis: 1386793879838] [levelValue: 800] [[
Initiating Jersey application, version Jersey: 2.0 2013-05-03 14:50:15...]]

[2013-12-11T21:31:20.186+0100] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [NCLS-JMX-00005] [javax.enterprise.system.jmx] [tid: _ThreadID=65 _ThreadName=Thread-6] [timeMillis: 1386793880186] [levelValue: 800] [[
JMXStartupService has started JMXConnector on JMXService URL service:jmx:rmi://192.168.0.11:8686/jndi/rmi://192.168.0.11:8686/jmxrmi]]

[2013-12-11T21:31:20.564+0100] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1386793880564] [levelValue: 800] [[
Grizzly Framework 2.3.1 started in: 1ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:7.676]]]

[2013-12-11T21:31:20.629+0100] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [NCLS-BOOTSTRAP-00027] [javax.enterprise.bootstrap] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1386793880629] [levelValue: 800] [[
Registered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishImpl@282b811a as OSGi service registration: org.apache.felix.framework.ServiceRegistrationImpl@55e6d9e8.]]

[2013-12-11T21:33:21.032+0100] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=73 _ThreadName=PingService] [timeMillis: 1386794001032] [levelValue: 800] [[
Domain Pinged: release.glassfish.org]]
```

How can i get my glassfish starting?

EDIT:

I cancelled the startup and restarted my pc. after i tried to start the 
glassfish again he stopped exactly at the same position. he just does 
not start up in eclipse. starting my domain using the console works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling the Eclipse Plugin solved the Problem.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this problem. This helped me to resolve the issue:

- If you are using glassfish 4.0 zip version inside `C:\ProgramFiles\`
  the server doesn't start inside eclipse due to administration
  problems.
- Copy glassfish 4.0 directory to other drive except `C:\ProgramFiles\`
  and reconfigure it to eclipse IDE.
- Keep it mind to remove previous glassfish configurations from Server
  Runtime Environments.